# How to create Pulseaudio virtual sink that you can hear?

Tags: pulseaudio

I wanted to setup OBS to record audio from a single application but I've tried every method I've seen and sometimes I can get OBS to record the audio but then I can't hear it.

Comment: A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Your question lacks the OS info. It does not list all the steps you have tried. Please EDIT the question and include this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out myself. As someone commented before, yes, I already have pavucontrol, but that wasn't working for me either. What I did was I made a virtual sink and a loopback of said sink. To do this, I used `pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=vsink` to create the sink, and `pactl load-module module-loopback sink=vsink` to create the loopback. Then I put the application that I wanted to record audio from onto vsink, and put the sink's loopback onto my desktop audio. This works when I run the commands through terminal but strangely doesn't work when I run them as a bash script. Instead of creating a sink and loopback it creates a loopback of my microphone. However I'm fine with the way it is now that it works.

Comment: How do you "put the sink's loopback onto your desktop audio"?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pavucontrol. From there it is easy to check different audio peripherals, whether they work or not.

`sudo apt install pavucontrol`